# In Android, how to hook api calls in another app

Tags: java, android, hook, xposed

there are two Android apps,A and B.
now, A executes a function(Af) which make the function(Bf) in B executed(Such as a Broadcast).
A and B running in different process(different uid)

I want to get the two functions name.

How can I get the name of Bf if I know Af?

or

How can I get the name of Af if I know Bf?

Answer (score 0):

if you know bf and want to get af, you can generate an exception in afterHookedMethod. I hope you know what that is. If you dont check out this link:

https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial

```
@Override
protected void afterHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
                  (new Exception()).printStackTrace();  
}
```

from the stack trace you can get the method call.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I have checked out the link. But, I think it still cannot get the Af.  If I hooked the Bf, it will be execute like B.before -> original method  -> B.after -> Af according to the help doc. When Bf is a broadcast sender, can I get the BroadcastReceiver Af ?